# Open GL ES creating Off-screen

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, pixmap

I am stuck with the following while creating OFF-SCREEN surface using OpenGL ES 2.0 :
    1. How to create Off-Screen surface using eglCreatePixmapSurface()? 
    2. eglCreatePixmapSurface() API takes **EGLNativePixmaptype** as parameter, what is                                 **EGLNativePixmaptype**? how to find its Structure definiton? Can i make it on my own? ( In my Code            base its declare as **void *** )
3.Once the drawing is done on a Native Pixmap surface, how to access my Native Pixmap data?

I have searched in internet alot but could find any relevant informative examples.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve? Any reason you want to use an EGLSurface for off-scree rendering, instead of simply using native OpenGL features (frame buffer objects)?

Comment: Reason for using off-screen rendering is because the off-screen surface is read by some viewer ( running in some remote display ) to display the content of off-screen surface.